# How can I make this recursive Binary Tree Traversal return null if the input is not found in the tree?

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

I am not sure how to make this recursive method return `null` if the char is not present in the tree.

```
BinaryTreeNode<CharData> answer; // Declare answer variable to use in findChar method

public BinaryTreeNode<CharData> findChar(char ch, BinaryTreeNode<CharData> root){

// Base Case
if (root.getValue().getChar() == ch){
        answer =  root; // If the node "root" contains the character, then answer becomes root node. 
    }
    // Otherwise finish pre-order traversal
else {

    // Check that left child is not null. If not, recursive call for left child.
    if(root.getLeft() != null){
        findChar(ch, root.getLeft());
    }

    // Check that right child is not null. If not, recursive call for right child. 
    if(root.getRight() != null)
        findChar(ch, root.getRight());
    }
    return answer;
}
```

As far as I can tell, `answer` has to be declared outside of the method in order for anything to be returned ever.

However, the problem is, when I am using a `for` a loop to search for a list characters and some do not exist in the BinaryTree, the value for answer returned for these nonexistent characters is whatever the value for answer was for the previous character in the list that existed in the binary tree. I would prefer if this method returned `null` for such values.

Comment: `search` in the method should be `root`

Comment: Oh yeah it is. I have been editing and playing around with this. I missed that. I will fix it to be what actually runs, but just not perfectly.

Comment: Ok. Now it is fixed. I had originally called the input node `search` but then I changed it to be `root` to follow convention to post it here, but I missed all the places I used the `root` or `search` node in the code. Oops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several observations
 1. A globally declared `answer` is a problem for several reasons.
 2. You are missing a further case: namely when `root` is `null`.
 3. `findChar` returns a value, you can use that.
 4. You do not make use of the fact that you have a search tree and always traverse the whole tree. I am assuming here that it really is a search tree, otherwise using a tree would not make sense.

So I suggest something like this:

```
public BinaryTreeNode<CharData> findChar(char ch, BinaryTreeNode<CharData> root){
    if (root == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (root.getValue().getChar() == ch){
        return root;
    }
    if (root.getValue().getChar() > ch) {
        return findChar(ch, root.getLeft());
    } else {
        return findChar(ch, root.getRight());
    }
}
```

In case it is not a binary search tree something like this will work:

```
public BinaryTreeNode<CharData> findChar(char ch, BinaryTreeNode<CharData> root){
    if (root == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (root.getValue().getChar() == ch){
        return root;
    }
    BinaryTreeNode<CharData> answer = findChar(ch, root.getLeft());
    if (answer != null) {
        return answer;
    } else {
        return findChar(ch, root.getRight());
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I see. Then just change the last `if` statement accordingly. I will add an update.

Comment: Ok. That gives me somewhere to go. However, the tree is a Binary Tree, not a Binary Search Tree. It is not organized based on the characters. `root.getValue()` returns the CharData object of that node. `root.getValue().getChar()` returns the character contained in the CharData contained in that node.